# Can we hide a Vlookup formula to enter new data in the same cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, vlookup

I have created a form in Google Sheets:

1. Row 5, `Client`, is a dropdown populated by existing clients.
2. Rows 6 to 9,  `Street Address`, `City`, `State`,  and `Post Code`, use VLOOKUP formulas to retrieve data from a separate sheet based on the `Client`
3. The `Client` dropdown is configured to "Show a warning" when invalid data is entered so that new clients can be added manually, as needed.
4. The image below shows sample data with a manually entered new client, `"BurgertTory (Southbank)"`:

   1. The validation warning shows on the `Client` dropdown cell (arrow in image).
   2. The VLOOKUP functions in the address rows each return a `#N/A` error because they fail to match the client name.

[image: Form]

Is there a way to create a toggle or checkbox so that the new client's address information can be entered in the address rows?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of including VLOOKUP formulas in the address rows, take a different approach.

Insert a row above `Street Address` (which will move it down to row 7.

Put an array formula in cell `D6` that will only populate the address rows if the client name exists in the master sheet.  Otherwise, it will do nothing leaving the rows available for data entry.

## Example

- For simplicity, the formula and the lookup data are in the same sheet in this example. You can separate them and adapt the formula to match your own lookup data.
- The formula cell, `c3` in the example` is always blank, however, you can add a string for new clients and/or existing clients.
- If left blank, you may prefer to hide the row.

#### Lookup Data

|  | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Clients** | **Street Address** | **City** | **State** | **Post Code** |
| **2** | Toys for Youz | 12 Elm St. | Yonkers | NY | 10470 |
| **3** | Shake Cabin | 13th St. W | Manhattan | NY | 10036 |
| **4** | BurgerTory (Northbank) | 1208 Surf Ave | Brooklyn | NY | 11224 |

#### Form

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** |  |  |  |  |
| **2** |  | **Client:** (Dropdown) | Shake Cabin |  |
| **3** |  |  | **`Formula`** |  |
| **4** |  | **Street Address:** | 13th St. W |  |
| **5** |  | **City:** | Manhattan |  |
| **6** |  | **State:** | NY |  |
| **7** |  | **Post Code:** | 10036 |  |

#### Formula in `C3`

```
=IFNA(IF(MATCH(C2,F:F,0),
  {"";TRANSPOSE(FILTER(G:J,F:F=C2))}))
```

[image: Sample formula in C3 showing the effect of using a new client versus an existing client and also hiding the formula's row]